# Permission denied with chmod 750 even if a user is just added to a group

Tags: linux, chown, permissions

I have a weird bug, I have:

- a user A
- a group B
- another group C

I create a folder and then chown it `A:B` and chmod it `750`.

After `usermod -aG A C`, C should have the right to go to the newly created folder, right? But it does not work all, I get a permission denied error.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The only people allowed to access the folder are:

user A: He is the owner
members of B: They can read/browse the folder

And that's it. The 0 in 750 means that other users won't be allowed to do anything with this folder. What you did was to add user A to the group C, but it doesn't affect the folder at all.

Comment: The OP usermod command would add a user C to group A, which doesn't match the explanation of the problem

Answer (score 2):

The synopsis for `usermod` from the man page is `usermod [options] LOGIN`.  Your command has the **group** last instead of the **login** last.

The group is an argument to the `-G` option.  It helps a little to separate options that require arguments from those that don't:

```
usermod -a -G C A
```

As @Rosco said, however, this still won't give A access to the directory.  You will either need to add A to the B group or change the group of the directory to C.

Answer (score 0):

```
usermod -aG A C
```

Adds user C to group A, however you haven't mentioned a group A.

Even if you did have a group A, the permissions on the folder are for user A, and group B, so membership to group A would not help.

To access the folder, you need to be either user A, or a member of group B. So running:

```
usermod -aG B C
```

Would allow user C to access the folder as a member of group B.